# Opencart SSL not Working

Tags: ssl, opencart

I'm using Opencart 3.0.2.0 version and trying to activate SSL on my website here is the URL goldqueen.in and did everything to activate SSL

1. update the config file
2. update admin/config file
3. activate SSL System>Setting>Server>Use SSL is ON

but did not work, please if anyone can help me to solve the SSL issue, I'm thankful to him.

Comment: as i can see SSL is active on your site

Comment: Yes but some file still got http url

Comment: which files can you send me those links